# My terminal takes a long time to respond to a command?

Tags: command-line, bash

My **terminal** takes more than 30 seconds to respond to any command I give.

When I try to run `sudo apt-get update`,
the password authentication line shows up after a long time.

What could be the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Does it happen with any terminal command, or just `sudo`? I bet your terminal is fine.

Comment: I would guess at the `/etc/hosts` file having been edited or incorrectly formatted.  Worth a look maybe?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev
 yes i found it happens just when running sudo commands

Comment: Try disabling your network and running the command again (I know `apt-get` will fail, but I'd expect `sudo` to react quicker if the issue is network-related).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly due to [NSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_Service_Switch). `sudo` (or any other program which needs to resolve names) may take a long time if it has to look up usernames or host names over the network.

First, try to understand which one is causing trouble. Take a look at [`nsswitch.conf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nsswitch.conf.5.html), or make a test with other NSS aware programs, like `ping` or `chmod`. If you have anything network-related configured for users (LDAP, NIS etc.), check that those services are available. If pinging your own host also takes lots of time, the issue is probably with hostname resolution, and you'll need to fix your DNS settings.

Checking `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/passwd` may also be worth a try, but I wouldn't expect failures with local files to introduce a 30 second delay.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `/etc/hosts` and make sure your *device name* is the same one written in the `hosts` file.  You can check it with:

```
sudo -e /etc/hosts
```